# Optimizing a MySQL query with inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to optimize my query here, but somehow it still takes 30+ seconds to execute.

This is how it looks:

```
SELECT v.cd, COUNT(vc.id) as count 
FROM vc
INNER JOIN v ON v.uid = vc.vid 
WHERE ct > 1393279200 AND pid="12" AND sid="10" 
GROUP BY vc.vid;
```

I have tried many combinations with JOIN,but it appears it's not a good idea to use JOIN at all. Maybe it would be better to build a subquery?

Desired result:

```
+--------------+--------------+
|      cd      |     count    |
+--------------+--------------+
| AE           |            1 |
| AM           |            1 |
| AU           |          230 |
| BB           |            1 |
| CA           |          127 |
| CH           |            1 |
| PR           |            3 |
| SA           |            1 |
| SE           |            5 |
| SG           |           12 |
| TH           |            1 |
| US           |         5829 |
| ZA           |            3 |
+--------------+--------------+
```

36 rows in set (41.09 sec)

Desired result generated by:

```
SELECT V.cd, COUNT(VC.id) as count 
FROM vc as VC, v V
WHERE ct > 1393279200 AND pid="12" AND sid="10" AND VC.vid = V.uid 
GROUP BY V.cd;
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `v.uid = vc.vid `

Comment: why do you group by `vc.vid`, but select `v.cd`? Give us table structure, sample data and desired result

Comment: Looks like an indexing issue. Joins are usually more efficient than subqueries... Can you share your schema?

Comment: Hey I updated my post. Checking indexes right now

Comment: I just fixed the indexed. I missed 2 indexes. 41 seconds turned into 0.18 seconds now. Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Create indexes:

1. `create index vcvid on vc (vid)`
2. `create unique index vuidcd on v (uid, cd)`

NOTE: Columns which are used in where statement should be in indexes too, usually first ones

run `analyze v; analyze vc; optimize v; optimize vc;`

then try this query:

```
select v.cd, q.cnt
from
v use index (vuidcd)
inner join
(
    select vc.vid, count(*) as cnt
    from vc use index (vcvid)
    group by vc.vid
) as q
on (v.uid = q.vid)
```

if there are will be problems - try to use `explain extended` with query to find problem

Comment: Yes, I had to create 2 indexes and now it's over 40x times faster :)

Comment: @Jason yeah, missed your comment :) anyway - check this variant, maybe will be even more faster